# How to make Drag and Drop work Horizontally?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to get Drag and Drop to work correctly

But in the image gallery, it only changes the position of the photo when dragging it under the other image

As if it only works vertically

[Demo](https://codepen.io/jonathan_silva/pen/NWBGyxB?editors=1011)

**Javascript Vanilla**

```
const enableDragSort = className => {
    // Gets all child elements of the .gallery or .datasheet class
    [...document.getElementsByClassName(className)].forEach(enableDragList);
}

const enableDragList = className => {
    // For each child of the class, add the draggable attribute
    [...className.children].forEach(enableDragItem);
}

const enableDragItem = item => {
    item.setAttribute('draggable', true);
    item.ondrag = handleDrag;
    item.ondragend = handleDrop;
}

const handleDrag = event => {
    const item = event.target.closest('[draggable]');
    item.classList.add('drag-sort-active');

    // .gallery or .datasheet
    const className = item.parentElement;

    const x = event.clientX;
    const y = event.clientY;

    let swap = document.elementFromPoint(x, y) ?? item;

    if (className === swap.parentElement) {
        swap = (swap !== item.nextSibling) ? swap : swap.nextSibling;

        className.insertBefore(item, swap);
    }
}

const handleDrop = ({ target }) => {
    const item = target.closest('[draggable]');
    item.classList.remove('drag-sort-active');
}

// Drag Drop
enableDragSort('gallery'); // It does not work properly
enableDragSort('datasheet'); // It works
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding attribute `draggable` to `div` wrapper, not the `image` itself. That means you need to drag over the div to make it work.

The quickest solution I come up is adding property `pointer-events: none;` to `.picture img` styles.

```
.picture img {
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 125px;
    object-fit: contain;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    pointer-events: none; // add this line
}
```

What it does, (in short) it makes the `img` "transparent" for the mouse events.